# Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, fuel-sdk, ruby-on-rails

I have developed a **Rails** app with [FuelSDK-Ruby](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Ruby) gem which will create / update the Data Extension records in Marketing Cloud.

On updating the records in Data Extension, Marketing Cloud responds with the below error:

> Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

I will filter the Data Extension records by passing the filter `{Property: 'field_name', SimpleOperator: 'IN', Value: ['asdff', 'asdfds']}` in the `MarketingCloudSDK::DataExtension::Row` **GET** API to decide whether to update or create a Data Extension record based on the response.

The record on which the error occurs was returned in the Data Extension GET API but, when trying to update the record using `MarketingCloudSDK::DataExtension::Row` **PATCH** method, the above mentioned error was returned.

Can anyone please tell me the cause for this issue and solution to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, did you come out with a solution to this issue ? I'm facing the same one currently .. thanks

Comment: Nope. We are still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to update a primary key field in a Data Extension.
Solutions:

- Remove the PK attribute from the field.
- Do not update a PK field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).